I need some help calculating some Denavit-Hartenberg parameters
I'm new here. Nice to meet you!
I am struggling to calculate some Denavit - Hartenberg parameters of 2 joints of a 6 degree of freedom robot.
I'm having trouble trying to calculate the Denavit Hartenberg parameters of the G2 joint. Joint G1 can rotate with respect to the y0 axis. How do I get from the coordinate system of joint 1 to the coordinate system of joint G2, which rotates with respect to z0 and is separated by a right-angle link? I've been trying all day to find the DH parameters (theta,d,a,alpha) to go from one system to another and I can't find it.
Here's a picture of the robot and the coordinate systems of the joints (x axis in blue, y axis in green, z axis in red).
Thanks!

[

Please edit your question to show what you're trying and why you think it's not working. Otherwise you're just going to get pointers to books or other resources.
